# mySQL/PHP - How do I post a creation date to a new table entry?

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, user-accounts

Cutting to the chase, I'm working on a **forum-like website using PHP, Bootstrap and mySQL** as part of a university assignment.

I managed to get some of the basics working - creating new user accounts as well as new threads to be viewed by the general public.

Sadly, there a lot of things I don't know how to do - one of them, in question, happens to be **recording the current date whenever I create a new user account or forum thread.**

For instance, I want each new record under the *users*table (storing data of all existing user accounts in mySQL) to have their own creation dates, the exact date they were made.

**Here's what I tried so far...**

The following piece of code is the top of my user registration file in PHP format.

```
<?php require_once('../private/initialize.php'); ?>

<?php
if(is_post_request()) {
    $user = [];
    $user['username'] = $_POST['username'] ?? '';
    $user['email'] = $_POST['email'] ?? '';
    $user['password'] = $_POST['password'] ?? '';
    $user['confirm_password'] = $_POST['confirm_password'] ?? '';
    $mysqldate = $_POST['joined_date'] ?? '';


    $result = insert_user($user); //Keep this function in mind, readers
    if($result === true) {
        $new_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
        log_in_user($user);
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'You successfully created a new account.';
        redirect_to(url_for('/index.php'));
    } else {
        $errors = $result;
    }
} else {
        $user = [];
        $user['username'] = '';
        $user['email'] = '';
        $user['password'] = '';
        $user['confirm_password'] = '';
        $user['joined_dated'] = '';
    }
?>
```

**To put everything into context,** my website is structured into two folders:
'public' (containing files to be accessed by the general public) and 'private' (files containing common functions used across the entire site accessed with the require and include PHP functions.

The **initialize.php** file that the require_once line refers to contains a host of *require_once* lines that call up the rest of those files I mentioned. Without it, the site fails to function.

**Note:** *I have edited the code to only show the information relevant to this post.*

```
<?php

  session_start(); // turn on sessions 

  require_once('query_functions.php');

  $db = db_connect();
  $errors = [];

?>
```

**query_functions.php**

```
function insert_user($user) {
        global $db;

        $errors = validate_user($user);
        if (!empty($errors)) {
            return $errors;
        }

        $mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate );
        $phpdate = strtotime( $mysqldate );

        $hashed_password = password_hash($user['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users ";
        $sql .= "(username, email, hashed_password, joined_date) ";
        $sql .= "VALUES (";
        $sql .= "'" . db_escape($db, $user['username']) . "',";
        $sql .= "'" . db_escape($db, $user['email']) . "',";
        $sql .= "'" . db_escape($db, $hashed_password) . "',";
        $sql .= "'" . db_escape($db, $mysqldate) . "'";
        $sql .= ")";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

        // For INSERT statements, $result is true/false
        if($result) {
            return true;
        } else {
            // INSERT failed
            echo mysqli_error($db);
            db_disconnect($db);
            exit;
        }
    }
```

These two codes,
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate );
$phpdate = strtotime( $mysqldate );

I tried them after reading one of the articles I found. It kind of
recorded a date in every new user account, except those dates always show as "*0000-00-00*".

Every other article I found so far shows a code solution that doesn't
exactly follow the formula I wrote down (which I learned from a course on Lynda.com - https://www.lynda.com/PHP-tutorials/PHP-MySQL-Essential-Training-1-Basics/587674-2.html)

So hopefully I've explained everything there is to know about my problem. So what am I missing? What am I doing wrong? How do I finally get the site to record the current date to put into each new user account?

Thanks.

Comment: `$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate );   $phpdate = strtotime( $mysqldate );` replace these two line with `$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: `INSERT INTO ..., joined_date = NOW()` gives you the time of inserttion.

Comment: As @Michel says, just use `NOW()` in your SQL; that’s what it’s for. Also, you should really read about how to create a [mcve]. There is a tremendous amount of irrelevant information in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **query_function.php**, `$phpdate` is undefined :

```
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate );
```

And this line is unused :

```
$phpdate = strtotime( $mysqldate );
```

Replace those both lines by this one :

```
$mysqldate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: I just did exactly what you suggested! And by Steve Jobs, it worked! I tested by creating a new user account and it showed today's date! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark your problem as resolved by upvoting my answer and accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Its simpler to get MySQL to do all the work for you and use the `NOW()` SQL Function

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users ";
$sql .= "(username, email, hashed_password, joined_date) ";
$sql .= "VALUES (";
$sql .= "'" . db_escape($db, $user['username']) . "',";
$sql .= "'" . db_escape($db, $user['email']) . "',";
$sql .= "'" . db_escape($db, $hashed_password) . "',";
$sql .= "NOW()";
$sql .= ")";
```